# Salesforce community as IDP not working when using custom login page

Tags: lightning-community, open-id-connect, identity-provider

I've to use Salesforce customer community as IdP for one of my external portal(SP) which is built on   Angular framework. We're trying  to use web server Oauth flow where grant type is authorization code and Open Id Connect as Scope. Connected app is properly set up as per my understanding
This works perfectly fine if I use Salesforce provided 'login page'. In other words, following happens correctly:

1. User clicks login button on SP(external button)
2. User is redirected to login page(standard login page) of Salesforce community
3. After successful login, user is asked to approve the App access
4. After user gives approval, user is successfully logged in-authenticated state to external portal.

But Step 3 & 4 doesn't occur, if **I use 'custom login page' in the community**. User is able to login but getting directed to home page of the community instead of returning back to calling portal. This login page is a lightning page built on AURA using simple lighting component, which calls method of apex controller to confirm the login. What is surprising is result I'm seeing through debug log:

1. There is no trace of apex controller created for login purpose.
2. After login(if apex controller not called, then not sure, how login is happening), page which is set as active site home page(see figure below), is called  which is a standard salesforce provided page,  Providing its screen shot below and code of login controller below.

please suggest what I'm doing wrong and how to send control back to calling portal, instead of community home page

[image]

Controller Code :

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static string loginSalesforce(String username, String password, String startUrl) { 
    try {
          ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(username, password, 'mystartURL');
        aura.redirect(lgn); 
        return 'Login Success';
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi all, just to reiterate, any  suggestion(small/big) is welcome as I'm completely stuck. All I want is, if Salesforce is able to return to calling portal using standard login page, what I've to do to ensure the same using custom login page? Why it is going to home page of community after login. How to ensure first step of oAuth,(/authorize) call get completed successfully with calling portal successfully getting auth code via callback URL, eg. something like this (https://myportal.com/oauth2/callback?
code=aPrx4sgoM2Nd1zWeFVlOWveD0HhYmiDiLmlLnXEBgX01tpVO==) happens successfully?

Comment: Another surprising thing is, This problem is occuring only for first time. In other words, when login page/authentication takes place. If suppose Calling portal tries again in separate tab 2nd time(since authentication is already succesful and no need of login page), then It succesfully gets auth code. so it is the login page which is culprit. I'm unsure what to do as custom login page is definitely required for branding purpose.